# Estimate pose of moving camera from a stationary camera, both looking at the same scene

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

Assume I have two independent cameras looking at the same scene (there are features that are visible from both) and that I know the calibration parameters of both the cameras individually (I can also perform stereo calibration at a certain baseline but I don't know if that would be useful). One of the cameras is fixed and stable, the other is noisy in terms of its pose (translation and rotation). As the pose keeps changing over time, is it possible to accurately estimate the pose of the moving camera with respect to the stationary one using image data from both cameras (in opencv)?

I've been doing a little bit of reading, and this is what I've gathered so far:

1. Find features using SIFT and the point correspondences.
2. Find the fundamental matrix.
3. Find essential matrix and perform SVD to obtain the R and t values between the cameras.

Does this approach work on a frame-by-frame basis? And how does the setup help in getting the scale factor? Pointers and suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Is the pose of the second camera noisy (there's a significant difference between where it is and where it should be) or does the second camera just move? (2) Does the scene you're observing change?

Comment: It's noisy. The application I am taking into account is something like this: there are two quadcopters trying to perform stereo vision with their individual cameras. I am assuming one of them has good stability, and the other is noisy because of its inherent issues. I would ideally like to stabilize the second one to obtain a certain baseline, but for now I am only worried about the estimation part and not the stabilizing part. The reason I am considering two quadcopters is for a decoupled stereo mechanism to map large objects.

Comment: So the first (more stable) camera also moves, but more reliably?

Comment: For now, (as part 1 of this problem), it is not. It is fixed. The features in the scene could be in motion, hence the reference camera is fixed in position and stays there.